# 3d algorithm for "magnetic distortion" of vertices

Tags: 3d, three.js

Given a solid, non-textured 3D shape made up of triangle vertices, and access to its array of vertices with all the x, y, z points, how would one implement several "magnetic" fields to distort this shape? Say, every magnetic field is a point of random in- or outside-object position x, y, z, as well as a strength; if it's near a vertex of this shape, it would "pull" it towards it, the nearer the stronger (also adjusted by its strength value)... leading to smooth bumps and budges.

I'm working with ThreeJS (JavaScript/ WebGL) at the moment, so help in JavaScript, ThreeJS or pseudocode might be perfect, but anything works! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want are implicit surfaces or metaball-like behavior. Look [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/exploring-metaballs-and-isosurfaces-in-2d-r2556) for (IMO) a very nice explanation of the basics behind implicit surfaces. Once you understand the concept, it is very easy to extend this to 3D. Also note that you don't have to construct the triangulation yourself (since you already have a mesh).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start! Wouldn't the behavior of metaballs to "merge" get in the way?

Comment: Well - the "magnet" wouldn't have any geometry, so no worries there. And you can limit the vertex stretching effect by limiting the deformation when the distance of of the center of the mesh-metaball goeas beyond a set distance of the centroid of the mesh). Something like an elastic limit on the mesh.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! On a sidenote, there's also a Metaball implementation in ThreeJS (http://ro.me/tech/metaball-playground).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert to implicit surfaces (as described by @ananthonline), you can just tweak all the vertices based on the "magnet" strength and location.  Note that the following will not create any new vertices, just attract existing ones;  this could be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on your application.

Given a magnet location `M`, you can tweak each vertex `V` to a new location `V'` as follows:

```
point V =     [incoming vertex]
point M =     [magnet location]
float range = [chosen nominal range for the magnetic effect]

float range2 = range * range  [range squared, for comparison with squared distance]
vector MV = V - M             [vector from M to V]
float alpha = range2 / (range2 + dot(MV, MV))  [weighting factor]
point V' =  alpha * M + (1-alpha) * V          [new, "magnetized" position]
```

Vertices several times the `range` distance from `M` will be only minimally affected.  Vertices within the `range` will be strongly attracted, but they won't go crazy.  Each magnetized vertex will be somewhere on the line between `M` and its original position, which will create a "pucker" effect:  the magnetized locations will be denser near the magnet, at the expense of the region they were attracted from.

If you don't like the exact shape of the magnetic effect (e.g., if you want to make sure that vertices beyond a certain distance don't move at all), you can tweak the formula for `alpha`.  Just make sure that `alpha` doesn't exceed `1`, and approaches `0` as the `dot(MV, MV)` becomes large.

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly sure what this would look like in JavaScript, but perhaps this is the answer.

Comment: Would be a pleasure if you could also have a look at my try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141139/3d-algorithm-for-magnetic-distortion-of-vertices/11145657#11145657

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about three.js, but I do know stuff about parabolas. And it seems like that is something that you could use.

This doesn't seem like an answer, but look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HvZHo-LSvQ. The video shows you how to draw a parabola. In your case, the focus point is a point that is inside the object (`strength of magnet = depth of focus point`), the origin of your axes is the magnet and the y-axis will be the normal of your vertex.

Performing this method will unfortunately give you cut edges and you will definitely need some kind of sinusoid instead, but I hope that this gives you a hint of how to move on. I will look further for you, but this was my first intuition.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following ThreeJS to work somewhat though it might be off in some parts, and the effect perhaps doesn't yet look too convincing, I'm not sure. The distortViaMagnets function is the core of the issue (full running [HTML and source here](http://outer-court.com/3d/magnetic.zip); running [demo here](http://outer-court.com/3d/magnetic/)):

```
'use strict';
var app = null;

window.onload = function() {
    app = new App();
    app.init();
}

App.prototype.init = function() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.addCamera();
    this.addLights();
    this.addSphere();
    this.addRenderer();
    this.render();
    app.animate();
};

App.prototype.distortViaMagnets = function() {
    var maxMagnets = this.magnets.length, maxVertices = this.sphere.geometry.vertices.length;
    var magneticMaxValue = this.getDistance3d( {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}, {x: 1000, y: 1000, z: 1000} );
    var strength = 1000, factor = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxMagnets; i++) {
        for (var vertexI = 0; vertexI < maxVertices; vertexI++) {
            var magnet = this.magnets[i];
            var vertex = this.sphere.geometry.vertices[vertexI];

            var distance = this.getDistance3d(magnet, vertex);
            var power = magneticMaxValue / distance / strength;

            vertex.x += ( (magnet.x - vertex.x) * power ) * factor;
            vertex.y += ( (magnet.y - vertex.y) * power ) * factor;
            vertex.z += ( (magnet.z - vertex.z) * power ) * factor;
        }
    }
}

App.prototype.animate = function() {
    app.mainGroup.rotation.y -= .003;

    requestAnimationFrame(app.animate);
    app.renderer.render(app.scene, app.camera);
};

App.prototype.addCamera = function() {
    this.camera = new THREE.CombinedCamera(this.width, this.height, 45, 1, 10000);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 400 - 200);
    this.camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0) );
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
}

App.prototype.addSphere = function() {
    this.mainGroup = new THREE.Object3D();

    var radius = 50, segments = 30 * 3, rings = 30 * 3;
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings);
    geometry.dynamic = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xffffff, opacity: 1} );
    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.sphere.dynamic = true;
    this.sphere.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    this.sphere.doubleSided = true;

    this.addMagnets();
    this.distortViaMagnets();

    this.mainGroup.add(this.sphere);

    this.scene.add(this.mainGroup);
}

App.prototype.addMagnets = function(vertex) {
    var max = this.sphere.geometry.vertices.length, maxMagnets = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var index = Misc.getRandomInt(0, max - 1);
        var vertex = app.sphere.geometry.vertices[index];
        var magnetI = this.magnets.length;
        this.magnets[magnetI] = this.distortVertex( {x: vertex.x, y: vertex.y, z: vertex.z}, 10 );
        this.showMagnet(this.magnets[magnetI]);
    }

    var magnetI = 0;
    this.magnets[magnetI] = {x: 58, y: 0, z: 0};
    this.showMagnet(this.magnets[magnetI]);
}

App.prototype.getDistance3d = function(vertex1, vertex2) {
    var xfactor = vertex2.x - vertex1.x;
    var yfactor = vertex2.y - vertex1.y;
    var zfactor = vertex2.z - vertex1.z;
    return Math.sqrt( (xfactor*xfactor) + (yfactor*yfactor) + (zfactor*zfactor) );
}

App.prototype.showMagnet = function(vertex) {
    var radius = 1.5, segments = 10, rings = 10;
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x11ee33, opacity: .6} );
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    sphere.position.set(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

    this.mainGroup.add(sphere);
}

App.prototype.distortVertex = function(vertex, distortion) {
    vertex.x = Misc.distort(vertex.x, distortion);
    vertex.y = Misc.distort(vertex.y, distortion);
    vertex.z = Misc.distort(vertex.z, distortion);
    return vertex;
}

App.prototype.addRenderer = function() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );
    this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
    var elmMain = document.getElementById('main');
    elmMain.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
}

App.prototype.render = function() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};

App.prototype.addLights = function() {
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(-50, 250, 250);
    this.scene.add(light);
};

function App() {
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.camera = null;
    this.sphere = null;
    this.controls = null;
    this.mainGroup = null;
    this.renderer = null;
    this.scene = null;
    this.magnets = [];
    this.debugElm = null;
}
```

Comment: To make this similar to my answer, try replacing `magneticMaxValue / distance` with `1/(1 + distance*distance/(magneticMaxValue*magneticMaxValue))`.